# Pronoms relatifs qui désigne un ou plusieurs noms?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord, pronoms-relatifs, syntaxe

Dans certaines phrases qui ont plusieurs sujets joints par "et", peut-on dire que parfois il y a deux sens?

Par exemple dans cette phrase ci: *"nous avons ramené le chat et les chiens qui sont morts"*?

1. = *nous avons ramené le chat (vivant) et les chiens (morts)* Si "qui sont morts" ne se rapporte qu'aux chiens?
2. = *nous avons ramené le chat (morts) et les chiens (morts)* Si "qui sont morts" se rapporte aux deux?

Si c'est le cas, est-ce que ces phrases sont correctement écrites?

- *J'ai* [*des chiens*] *et* [*un chat qui est bête*].
- *J'ai* [*des chiens*] *et* [*un chat*] *qui sont bêtes*.
- *Ce sont* [*les chiens*] *et* [*le chat que j'ai aimé*].
- *Ce sont* [*les chiens*] *et* [*le chat*] *que j'ai aimés*.

Comment: Oui et oui à part la 3ème phrase qui est bancale hors contexte ("ce sont les chiens" pris tout seul n'a guère de sens... quels chiens ?)

Comment: Pour être bien compris à l’oral il vaut  mieux spécifier «les xxx qui sont mort» en premier afin de faire compte  que les deuxièmes ne le sont pas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour éviter toutes ambiguïtés il suffit ajouter des virgules:

- nous avons ramené le chat, et les chiens qui sont morts.
- nous avons ramené le chat et les chiens, qui sont morts.

Si le problème se présente pendant un discours oral il n’y a qu’à faire des pauses:

- nous avons ramené le chat (pause) et aussi les chiens qui sont morts.
- nous avons ramené le chat et les chiens (pause) qui sont morts.

Avec ça il n’y a plus d’ambiguïté.

Les autres phrases sont correctes et sans ambiguïtés car le problème se présente seulement quand le sujet qui précède le pronom relatif pluriel est pluriel (aucune ambiguïté dans les autres cas, évidemment).